# Eclipse indigo 3.7.2 java/flex 4.6 project remote objects not working for default?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, jakarta-ee, apache-flex, flex4.6

I have flash builder 4.6 plugin installed on eclipse indigo 3.7.2 x32 (couldn't install flash builder on juno), and deploying as an ear on a jboss 7.1 server testing on localhost.

So after creating a new flex/java project using WTP, and for remote objects "services ADEP Data Services for Java EE 4.6" dataservices war file, for default, any remote object i call on my just created clean project gives me a "Client.Error.MessageSend Send failed" popup with no trace stack on the console or any sing of an error...

MXML

```
<s:RemoteObject
        id="testRO"
        destination="test"
        fault="loginRO_faultHandler(event)"
        result="loginRO_resultHandler(event)"/>
```

remoting-config.xml

```
<service id="remoting-service" 
class="flex.messaging.services.RemotingService">

<adapters>
    <adapter-definition id="java-object" class="flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter" default="true"/>
</adapters>

<default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-amf"/>
</default-channels>
<destination id="test">
    <properties>
        <source>architecture.controller.TestCon</source>
        <scope>application</scope>
    </properties>
</destination>
```

TestCon.java

```
package architecture.controller;

import com.sun.istack.internal.logging.Logger;

public class TestCon {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestCon.class);
    public void test(){
        logger.info("testing");
    }
}
```

Also tried lcds 3.1 and some pdf steps that suggest to import the war file and then add/change project type to Flex project without any luck.

I have other projects made in flash builder 4.0 deployed on the same server communicating with remote objects working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.... turns out i had imported **com.sun.istack.internal.logging.Logger** instead of **org.apache.log4j.Logger**.

I guess the true problem here was the misleading error message and the console not showing the trace stack.